# How to remove duplicate entries from a dictionary within a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal of my code is that no more than one individual with the same name and birth date should appear in a file I'm parsing.

Here is my dictionary within a dictionary which is called ind:

```
{I19: {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}}
{I32: {'BIRT': '27 MAY 1991', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I32', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Nick /Tary/'}}
{I30: {'BIRT': '3 SEP 1993', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I30', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Mary /Test/'}}
{I26: {'BIRT': '2 JUN 1983', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I26', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jane /Smith/'}}
{I01: {'name': 'Joe /Smith/', 'family': 'F23', 'BIRT': '15 JUL 1960', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I01', 'DEAT': '31 DEC 2013'}}
{I07: {'BIRT': '23 SEP 1960', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I07', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jennifer /Smith/'}}
{I19: {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}}
```

My code should get rid of one of Dick Smith's entries since there's 2.

Here is my code for this part so far (doesn't remove a duplicate yet):

```
for individual in ind:
    name1 = ind[individual]['name']
    bdate1 = ind[individual]['BIRT']
    for individual_2 in ind:
        name2 = ind[individual]['name']
        bdate2 = ind[individual]['BIRT']
        if name1 == name2 and bdate1 == bdate2:
            print("{} already exists. Removing duplicate entry.".format(name1))
```

but that gives me:

```
Dick /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Dick /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Dick /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Dick /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Dick /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Dick /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Nick /Tary/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Nick /Tary/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Nick /Tary/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Nick /Tary/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Nick /Tary/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Nick /Tary/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Mary /Test/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Mary /Test/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Mary /Test/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Mary /Test/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Mary /Test/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Mary /Test/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jane /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jane /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jane /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jane /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jane /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jane /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Joe /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Joe /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Joe /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Joe /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Joe /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Joe /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jennifer /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jennifer /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jennifer /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jennifer /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jennifer /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
Jennifer /Smith/ already exists. Removing duplicate entry.
```

Apologies if the question seems easy - I'm new to this. Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: you can build a new dict with names as keys

Comment: How are you "building" the initial dict?  If you structure the multi-level dict differently then it might work better.  Have a dict for each level of uniqueness you require: `ind[individual]['name']['BIRT']`  then as you add items to the dict the first time you see Mr Smith his "record" will be created.  Each future time you see his record the previous one will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_of_dict = [{'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}},
     {'I32': {'BIRT': '27 MAY 1991', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I32', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Nick /Tary/'}}
,{'I30': {'BIRT': '3 SEP 1993', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I30', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Mary /Test/'}}
,{'I26': {'BIRT': '2 JUN 1983', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I26', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jane /Smith/'}}
,{'I01': {'name': 'Joe /Smith/', 'family': 'F23', 'BIRT': '15 JUL 1960', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I01', 'DEAT': '31 DEC 2013'}}
,{'I07': {'BIRT': '23 SEP 1960', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I07', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jennifer /Smith/'}}
,{'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}}]

new_d = {v['name'] : {k : v} for d in list_of_dict for k,v in d.items()}

for v in new_d.values():
    print(v)
```

output

```
{'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}}
{'I32': {'BIRT': '27 MAY 1991', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I32', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Nick /Tary/'}}
{'I30': {'BIRT': '3 SEP 1993', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I30', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Mary /Test/'}}
{'I26': {'BIRT': '2 JUN 1983', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I26', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jane /Smith/'}}
{'I01': {'name': 'Joe /Smith/', 'family': 'F23', 'BIRT': '15 JUL 1960', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I01', 'DEAT': '31 DEC 2013'}}
{'I07': {'BIRT': '23 SEP 1960', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I07', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jennifer /Smith/'}}
```

Note that in this impl only the last name is saved in case of dup

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `itertools` recipe [`unique_everseen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), available in the standard library. If you have access to the 3rd party `toolz` library, you can use `toolz.unique`.

We define a function by which we determine whether a dictionary is unique. In this case, we need only check the `name` key of each dictionary.

Using this technique, the *first occurrence only* is stored for each unique name.

```
from toolz import unique

res = list(unique(ind, lambda x: next(iter(x.items()))[1]['name']))
```

**Setup**

```
ind = [{'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}},
       {'I32': {'BIRT': '27 MAY 1991', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I32', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Nick /Tary/'}},
       {'I30': {'BIRT': '3 SEP 1993', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I30', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Mary /Test/'}},
       {'I26': {'BIRT': '2 JUN 1983', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I26', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jane /Smith/'}},
       {'I01': {'name': 'Joe /Smith/', 'family': 'F23', 'BIRT': '15 JUL 1960', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I01', 'DEAT': '31 DEC 2013'}},
       {'I07': {'BIRT': '23 SEP 1960', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I07', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jennifer /Smith/'}},
       {'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}}]
```

**Result**

```
[{'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}},
 {'I32': {'BIRT': '27 MAY 1991', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I32', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Nick /Tary/'}},
 {'I30': {'BIRT': '3 SEP 1993', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I30', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Mary /Test/'}},
 {'I26': {'BIRT': '2 JUN 1983', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I26', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jane /Smith/'}},
 {'I01': {'name': 'Joe /Smith/', 'family': 'F23', 'BIRT': '15 JUL 1960', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I01', 'DEAT': '31 DEC 2013'}},
 {'I07': {'BIRT': '23 SEP 1960', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I07', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jennifer /Smith/'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is already an entire dictionary, then duplicates will be removed since `'I19'` appears twice. However, if your data is a list of dictionaries, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
def depth_key(x):
  [[_, c]] = list(x.items())
  return [c['name'], c['BIRT']]

d = [{'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}}, {'I32': {'BIRT': '27 MAY 1991', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I32', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Nick /Tary/'}}, {'I30': {'BIRT': '3 SEP 1993', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I30', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Mary /Test/'}}, {'I26': {'BIRT': '2 JUN 1983', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I26', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jane /Smith/'}}, {'I01': {'name': 'Joe /Smith/', 'family': 'F23', 'BIRT': '15 JUL 1960', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I01', 'DEAT': '31 DEC 2013'}}, {'I07': {'BIRT': '23 SEP 1960', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I07', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jennifer /Smith/'}}, {'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}}]
new_d = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=depth_key), key=depth_key)]
final_d = [b for _, [b, *c] in new_d]
```

Output:

```
[{'I19': {'BIRT': '13 FEB 1981', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I19', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Dick /Smith/'}}, {'I26': {'BIRT': '2 JUN 1983', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I26', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jane /Smith/'}}, {'I07': {'BIRT': '23 SEP 1960', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I07', 'family': 'F23', 'name': 'Jennifer /Smith/'}}, {'I01': {'name': 'Joe /Smith/', 'family': 'F23', 'BIRT': '15 JUL 1960', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I01', 'DEAT': '31 DEC 2013'}}, {'I30': {'BIRT': '3 SEP 1993', 'sex': 'F', 'id': 'I30', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Mary /Test/'}}, {'I32': {'BIRT': '27 MAY 1991', 'sex': 'M', 'id': 'I32', 'family': 'F16', 'name': 'Nick /Tary/'}}]
```